# How to group rows of a dataframe without using the groupby() function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with student details, stream and percentage.I want to display student record with highest percentage of each stream without using groupby function on dataframe.

```
    name class section  marks roll grade

 damon     4       s   44.0    5   NaN

mehreen     4       s   85.0    4     B

  sara     4       a   96.0    5     A

 derya     5       s   49.0    a   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you wouldn't want to use groupby. However, if your goal is to see which students have the highest grades in each stream (I assume section = stream, but if it is something else it'll work the same way) then you can do this:

```
     name  class section  marks roll grade
0    damon      4       s   44.0    5   NaN
1  mehreen      4       s   85.0    4     B
2     sara      4       a   96.0    5     A
3    derya      5       s   49.0    a   NaN
```

and

```
df2= df.sort_values(['marks','section'], ascending=False)
```

which gives you

```
      name  class section  marks roll grade
2     sara      4       a   96.0    5     A
1  mehreen      4       s   85.0    4     B
3    derya      5       s   49.0    a   NaN
0    damon      4       s   44.0    5   NaN
```

You had two streams a and s so the top 2 rows are just the students with highest grade in each stream.